# Javascript function to convert milliseconds yields strange results

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my own custom `TimeObject` class for a tiny web app I'm making.

Here I define a function to taken a valid-range, integer number of milliseconds, in order to instantiate a `TimeObject` as follows:

```
TimeObject.prototype.millisecondsToTime = function(mm) {
   function valid() {
        if(parseInt(mm,10) >= 0 && parseInt(mm,10) <= 359999999) return true;
    }
    if(valid()) {
        var h = Math.floor(mm/3600000);
        var m = Math.floor(((mm/3600000)-h)*60);
        var s = Math.floor(((((mm/3600000)-h)*60)-m)*60);
        var mmFinal = Math.floor(((((((mm/3600000)-h)*60)-m)*60)-s)*1000);
        this.hours = h,
        this.minutes = m;
        this.seconds = s;
        this.milliseconds = mmFinal;
    } else {
        this.hours = 0,
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.milliseconds = 0;
    }
}
```

It appears to work fine except for values that are 2^x:

```
// 2^0 = 1 -> returns 0, should return 1
// 2^1 = 2 -> returns 1, should return 2
// 2^2 = 4 -> returns 3, should return 4
// 2^3 = 8 -> returns 7, should return 8
// And so on...
```

Values such as `1001`, `1003`, but not `1002` and `1004` return `milliseconds` as `0` and `2` respectively. They should return `1` and `3` as the `milliseconds` value but don't.

I know it's a logical error, but what's going on here and how can I correct my code?

Comment: try using integer algebra instead of dividing and multiplying several times. remember that floating point operations lose decimal precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subtracting *smaller* elements from your timer first, progressively removing the smallest unit and then dividing by the number of values in that unit.

```
this.milliseconds = mm % 1000;
mm = (mm - this.milliseconds) / 1000;  // mm is now measured in whole seconds

this.seconds = mm % 60;
mm = (mm - this.seconds) / 60;  // mm is now measured in whole minutes

this.minutes = mm % 60; 
mm = (mm - this.minutes) / 60;  // mm is now measured in whole hours

this.hours = mm;
```

etc.  This will avoid any non-integer numbers from appearing in your calculations.

Comment: Not sure if you misinterpreted what I'm trying to do, but using your code works for all values of `mm` that are between `0` and `999`, but as soon as I pass in a value greater `999` I don't get what is expected. See here (open your console in your browser): http://jsfiddle.net/g4fwf5gt/

Comment: You would expect that `1000` sets `milliseconds` to `0` and `seconds` to `1`, as well as all other values appropriately depending on many milliseconds are passed in.

Comment: @nhuff717 yeah, sorry, I completely forgot about some of the factors of 1000.  The revised code should be simpler to understand, fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/vo07vkaa/

Comment: Maybe I'm just not good enough with math, but how would this function change for seconds instead of milliseconds? For instance, if I have 1000 seconds, do I still start with removing the smallest unit (milliseconds)? I'm writing one function for each type of unit (ms, s, m, h).

Comment: if your values are counted in seconds (i.e. Unix epoch time) simply remove the first two lines.